# Song in esperanto

Tags: literature

There was a song: "En vi kai mi", like "This is the moon and this is you" (or me I don't remember).

If you know it please tell the name and who sing it and where may I hear it again?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This song is called "Jen", it is sung by [La Porkoj](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Porkoj) and you can listen to it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nYAzPaV7sU).